# Force Gradle 4.3 to compile on Java 1.5

Tags: java, gradle, gradlew

Currently, I'm using gradle 4.3 and I'm trying to force it to use a jdk 1.0.5_22 to compile a legacy project. Gradle requires at least to be run on Java 7, but from what I saw on the internet it can be forced to use an earlier jdk to perform the compilation.

I used the following code in my **build.gradle** file:

```
compileJava.options.fork = true
compileJava.options.forkOptions.executable = C:/path/to/jdk.1.0.5_22/bin/javac.exe
```

but it still compiles with the JDK it is running on, which is a *1.8.0_151* JDK.

Am I doing something wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: I tried with Gradle 2.14.1, but it still doesn't compile on Java 5. It just ignores the JVM settings I give it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the docs Gradle will not compile anything before Java 1.6:
https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_plugin.html#sec:java_cross_compilation

Comment: Thanks, I missed that detail. What is the latest Gradle version that I can use to compile in Java 1.5?

Comment: Found it, it's version 2.14.1

Comment: @Fabrizio Roman Yoa are wrong. Java 1.5 and gradle 2.14.1 got "Gradle 2.14.1 requires Java 6 or later to run. Your build is currently configured to use Java 5."